# Displaying ASCII codes to an 7x5 LED Matrix

Tags: led, multiplexer, decoder, led-matrix

I want to know the best way to display ASCII binary code to a 7x5 LED matrix (cathode). The way I'm thinking to approach right now involves an decoder for each column (containing 7 bits, regarding the lines), and a multiplexer that receives the 35 decoded entries and outputs 7 bits. There is also a shift register in the same clock as the MUX to set HIGH in the columns the multiplexer set LOW the lines that are supposed to light. I wonder if that is the best way to do this, considering that the column decoder would be huge. Thanks for your time!
PS. Also, I forgot to mention, I am using a FPGA for this project
[image]

Comment: The typical approach is to scan across. You have 7 pins which control the row data, and then scan along each column in turn. So a total of 12 pins.

Comment: How can I do that? with decoders for each column (with the information of the row data)?

Comment: Are you using a microcontroller? If not, what is your data source?

Comment: It's coming from a shift register, that holds 56 bits (8 letters)

Comment: By "cathode" do you mean a vacuum fluorescent display (VFD) used mostly in the tape/cd/dvd players and set-top boxes? Would you be able to post a picture please?

Comment: @VictorMunduruca: It would help a lot if you were to use the schematic editor to provide a behavioral diagram. It's possible that we may project our own ideas onto your words and a diagram would help clear that up. The big problem I see (and I may be projecting here) is that you haven't discussed the memory required for a complete character set mapping from ASCII into all the 5x7 information required. You need to scan a ROM, I think. Most people would just use a micro for this. But it sounds as though you do not want to?

Comment: If not a picture, at least the model number+datasheet link of the matrix you are trying to use. Knowing the pinout would make writing an answer easier.

Comment: By cathode I meant that to light up a specific dot you'd have to set the row LOW and the columns HIGH. I'll post a picture

Comment: @jonk, agreed, I might have indeed projected my own ideas. But I mapped the characters already, I was going to create the decoders from that, actually. I forgot to mention, I am working with a FPGA

Answer (score 3):

- There is no best way without specifying constraints.
- Assuming you are only making 1 unit, the BOM cost is likely second
  after feature flexibility.
- Embedded processor provide flexibility far greater than combinational logic.

Normally, LED matrix displays such as these are not all tied to 1 common cathode.  Rather, they are arranged in a matrix:

[image]

Most embedded processors have enough programmable GPIO pins to drive such a display.  [Here](http://www.interactionlab.biz/v2/?p=176) is a project in which an Atmel embedded processor (Arduino) is used to drive an 8 x 8 LED matrix.

Once built, you can program the embedded processor to display your ASCII data in any number of ways.  As 5 binary 7 bit numbers in each of the 5 vertical columns.  As a graphical character as defined by this table:

[image]

Since an embedded processor is being used, you imagination is free to create any pattern to represent your data.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a FPGA like you said, then I would not use any external component, as the FPGA can handle this by itself.

I would simply use a signal that holds the values of each pixel (each dot of the matrix). Then I would make a clocked process that would scan through the lines (or columns) fast enough so the flickering is not visible to the human eyes.

It's basically like driving a 7-segment display except it has more pixels and you must deal with multiple common cathodes (or anodes depending on how the matrix is built).

Comment: That's what I was doing so far, I think it'll work, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The Maxim MAX7219 and MAX7221 were purpose-designed for 8x8 LED matrix displays. They are quite popular for exactly this application.

[image]